# How to compare below 2 arrays to find if there are simmiler words?

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare, opennlp

I need to compare below arrays and check whether there are similar words and if there are similar words then perform another task. Here for tockanization i have used Apache open NLP.

```
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.SimpleTokenizer;  
public class SimpleTokenizerExample { 
   public static void main(String args[]){ 

      String description = "This Book is about java Technologies";

      String request = "I need a java book" ;

      //Instantiating SimpleTokenizer class 
      SimpleTokenizer simpleTokenizer = SimpleTokenizer.INSTANCE;  

      //Tokenizing the given sentence 

      String tokens[] = simpleTokenizer.tokenize(description);

      String tokens2[]= simpleTokenizer.tokenize(request);

      //Printing the tokens 
      for(String token : tokens) {         
         System.out.println(token);  
      } 

      System.out.println("\n");

    //Printing the tokens 
      for(String token : tokens2) { 

         System.out.println(token);  
      }``

}}
```

The output is as below:

This

Book

is

about

java

Technologies

I

need

a

java

book

Comment: So you wish to count how many Strings are equal between two String arrays? If so, use a nested for loop. For each String in array#1, iterate through all Strings in array#2 and check to see if each String from array#1 equals (using the equals function for String instead of "==") any String from array#2

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a basic distance or similarity function on vectors.
In this case you have what is referred to sometimes as "term vectors."
So basically I suggest you make a `Map<String,Double>` out of your string arrays, and then use this function below (cosine similarity) to compare them.

```
 private Double compare(Map<String, Double> a, Map<String, Double> b) {
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
    keys.addAll(a.keySet());
    keys.addAll(b.keySet());
    Double dot = 0d, magA = 0d, magB = 0d;
    for (String key : keys) {
      Double aVal = a.get(key) == null ? 0d : a.get(key);
      Double bVal = b.get(key) == null ? 0d : b.get(key);
      magA += Math.pow(aVal, 2);
      magB += Math.pow(bVal, 2);
      dot += aVal * bVal;
    }
    if (dot == 0d) {
      return 0d;
    }
    Double div = Math.sqrt(magA) * Math.sqrt(magB);
    if (div == 0d) {
      return 0d;
    }
    return dot / div;
  }
```

then you would do something like this to call it on your two arrays of strings

```
 private static void compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
    Map<String, Double> ma = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Double> mb = new HashMap<>();

    for (String s : a) {
      if (ma.containsKey(s)) {
        ma.put(s, ma.get(s) + 1);
      } else {
        ma.put(s, 1d);
      }
    }
    for (String s : b) {
      if (mb.containsKey(s)) {
        mb.put(s, mb.get(s) + 1);
      } else {
        mb.put(s, 1d);
      }
    }

   Double score = compare(ma, mb);

  }
```

nice thing about cosine similarity is that it always returns a value between 0 and 1. You can use euclidean vector distance, or manhattan distance etc, but they don't produce a nice distribution like this.

Multidimensional math calculations will change the way you think about coding!

HTH

MG